# Set Params and Headers in axios post request

Tags: reactjs, api, post, axios, postman

I recently encounter a stupid problem in my app width an axios request.

Here is the query

```
const data =  { name: name }
const headers = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }

axios.post('http://localhost:3333/list/add', data, headers)
```

This request works but doesn't insert the name value...

When I console log the `data` variable I have the correct value and when I test this request on postman, it works perfectly.

Request on Postman
[image]

Request on my app
[image]

My API code

```
async add({ request, auth, response }) {
        try {
            const list = new List()

            let user = await User.find(auth.current.user.id)
            let name = request.get('name')

            list.fill(name)

            const result = await list.save()

            await Database
                .insert({'user_id': user.id, 'list_id': list.id})
                .into('users_has_lists')

            return response.json({
                query_name: 'add',
                status: 'success',
                data: list
            })

        } catch (error) {
            return response.status(400).json({
                status: 'error',
                message: error.message
            })
        }
    }
```

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this request ?

Thanks you in advance !

Comment: "doesn't insert the name value" could you elaborate that?

Comment: Did you try to log `token`? Its value could be the problem.

Comment: I mean that the token is good given that the request works fine (She insert the good user id)

The only problem is that the params are ignored and don't insert in the database.

When I test this request on Postman using the same token and the same params, it works.

Comment: Did you check that params in the netwrok tab?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb

Here is what I get : 

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/JOrrLFP.png)

Comment: So thats not an issue with your data variable, the data is passed correctly in the call, looks like an issue with the auth token

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb
Okay, I get it but I'm even more confused haha

Comment: I will love to clear your confusions and concerns surely.

Comment: From postman the data is being sent as query parameters while from axios it it being sent as post body. You need to make it consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2nd parameter in a post request count as body. To add params, you need to use another param. For your example, it should be

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3333/list/add', null, {headers:headers, params:data})
```